# Does bootstrap support left-navigation menus natively?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen some premium bootstrap themes with a left-navigation menu instead of the standard top-navigation, but I don't see this documented anywhere. Is this all custom CSS, or is it natively supported and I can't find the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [navbar](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) is a simple wrapper for positioning branding, navigation, and other elements into a concise navigation header. It’s easily extensible and, with the help of our collapse plugin, it can easily integrate offscreen content.

It's only for header. Head means top. You can modify it. As for your choice. You can move it in left. See some example.

In this [Example 1](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z4Q2r) codes are also given.

From [Example 2](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/), you will be able to download codes also.

Comment: This is a great approach, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for accepting it. Also can give an upvote.